# ActiveMQ for event driven architecture

Tags: architecture, event-sourcing, event-handling

I am using **ActiveMQ** and I have a scenario where I need to update the event for 100 consumers parallelly.

I am looking for a **solution** where the 100 consumers receive the event parallelly (i.e there shouldn't be inconsistency like few consumers received the data and few are yet to receive the data) so that only when all the consumers received the event I need to consider as event update is successful.

Is there an architecture available for this?

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: ...also, please don't **[cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info "'Cross-posting is frowned upon...'")**: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59450230/activemq-for-event-driven-architecture "Cross-posting is frowned upon as it leads to fragmented answers splattered all over the network..."

Answer (score 1):

> where the 100 consumers receive the event parallelly (i.e there shouldn't be inconsistency like few consumers received the data and few are yet to receive the data)

In the presence of network, there is no guarantee for all consumers to receive events at the same time. Why?

1. Data can be sent out in batches that is optimized for the transport layer
2. Packets can be dropped and redelivered
3. Receiving nodes have to send an acknowledgement to sending nodes
4. ... and several other problems that happen in distributed computing

> so that only when all the consumers received the event I need to consider as event update is successful.

What you are looking for is not a way for all consumers receive the event at the same time, but for all of them to return an acknowledgement to the sender.

An example of such a protocol is used in databases - [Write Concern in MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/write-concern/) determines whether a DB write is considered successful based on how many nodes acknowledge the write. You can study more into the database or read similar papers on how to implement such a protocol.

I have to caution that requesting an acknowledgement from 100 nodes to guarantee success is going to be a very expensive operation and likely won’t scale.